# .Net Core 5 Web Api services object sharing and refrence

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I Developed 2 WebApi in .net core 5 Like InventoryApi and SalesApi.
I have an object named Good in InventoryApi that use in StockIO's  .
The Good has relation with Salesinvoices object in SalesApi.

Which options do I have to reference them?

1. use shared class
2. reference InventoryApi in SalesApi  project and use Good Object from Inventory
3. any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

Since you have combined the API's in a single solution, the shared class, in a shared class library is fine.

---

I'll give you some options with pro's and con's. There are other ways, but I think these are most common.

1. Shared class, shared class library project
2. Shared class, shared API project
3. Shared library (nuget)
4. Loose coupling or redefine (nu reuse)

##### Shared class, shared class library project

This is a class accessible by code from within the solution by the 2 API projects.

Pro's

- easy to access
- rapid development
- dedicated project for all shared components

Cons

- entangles API's
- higher complexity (single class affects 2 systems)

##### Shared class, shared API project

Similar as above, but instead of sharing a shared component, you're shing the complete API project.

Pro's

- easy to access
- rapid development

Cons

- entangles API's
- higher complexity (single class affects 2 systems)
- expose full API project

##### Shared library (nuget)

Similar as the shared library, but in this case you use a package manager like nuget to manage the distribution and versions of the package. This is often used if the package needs to be shared with multiple components.

Pro's

- good if package/release management is required (due to many dependencies)

Cons

- more work to setup
- more work to apply change

##### Loose coupling or redefine (nu reuse)

If the shared class only contains data and is used as Data Transfer Objects (DTO), you can define it in both projects separately.

Pro's

- no shared dependent component

Cons

- risk of being misaligned

Comment: thank s a lot . do you suggest directly reference shared object  OR reference them from connected Api

Comment: The shared library - basically create a new class library project in the same solution and reference that project